# Lock screen ads on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, ads

I want to show ads or special offers in iPhone/iPad lock screen can any one guide me on this. How to implement? Any delegate methods available in iOS?
Will Apple approve if i do so for ads on lock screen? Any SDK supports?

Have seen some Android apps done this.

Comment: You can't on non jailbreaken token, but you could may be interested in iBeacon.

Answer (score 3):

Not possible.

You cannot detect power button clicks from the user. And, I believe this would be against [iAd Content Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/iad/content-guidelines/iAd_Content_Guidelines.pdf) too.

But, you can detect when a user presses the home button to leave your app and when they press the lock button to put your app into the background [using CSNotificationCenter](https://github.com/binarydev/ios-home-vs-lock-button).

Comment: then is it possible to show behind lock screen?

Comment: @Nagarjun I am afraid - not. Sorry, you need to understand the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/iAdRichMediaAds.html). If I have answered your query, please select the answer as right to consider the topic closed for other users which are asking the same question.

Answer (score 0):

As said before it is not possible, but I think you may use the push notification message to get the user attention to what you want to advertise, and when he unlock the notification your app launches and show the ads banner.